# Assign variable value to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$("#rate").live('blur', function(){
    var rate=$(this).val();
    var qty =$('#quantity').val();
    var amt=rate*qty;
    alert(amt);
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = amt;
});
```

Here I am getting the correct amount in `amt` variable . Now I just want to assign it to amount div. So how do I do that?

Comment: `$('#amount').html(amt);`

Comment: document.getElementById("amount").value = amt;

Comment: Why is this question tagged "php"?

Comment: it depends if your amount id is for input tag then you can use $('#amount').val(value to be passed); otherwise if your id is for div hen use $('#amount').html(value to be passed);

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Other than the fact that you're using `live` (which is deprecated & removed in jQuery 1.9) and mixing jQuery & Vanilla JS with `innerHTML`, this should work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/6eta0nLm/

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Comment: Although it isn't clear from you code (as there is no html in your example) if you are gettign values from inputs they will be strings not numbers, so rate * qty would give you NaN

Comment: @atmd Not true. Multiplication implies both sides are numbers so javascript implicitly converts them. Try it

Comment: @RGraham ha haa, I've actually just logged on to check that. Your right. Everyday's days a school day, thanks for the spot. Interestingly it also trims the input which i didn't know the coercion would do i.e. " 20" * "    5   "  and "          20" / "    2" still work.

Comment: My comment above has space before and after the numbers inside the string but its been formatted out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of jquery you are using. If it's greater than or equal to the version 1.9 , than the live function will not work. If so than use .on function instead. use the code be low

```
$("#rate").on('blur', function(){
    var rate=$(this).val();
    var qty =$('#quantity').val();
    var amt=rate*qty;
    alert(amt);
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = amt;
});
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: If you update this answer instead of posting a new one, whoever downvoted it could retract their vote and you can get your rep back again. Just FYI

Answer (score 1):

Hudixt's answer is right, however you'll need to parse the values as int (or float) if they are coming from inputs of a text type, as they are strings. i.e

```
$("#rate").on('blur', function(){
    var rate=$(this).val();
    var qty =$('#quantity').val();
    var amt= parseInt(rate) * parseInt(qty);
    alert(amt);
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = amt;
});
```

Trying to multiply two strings with give you a NaN

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#amount').text(amt);
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = amt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#amount").html(amt);  //in jquery

document.getElementById("amount").value = amt; //in Javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

You should user setAttribute method. There is my solution for your case :

```
$("#rate").live('blur', function(){
 var rate=$(this).val();
 var qty =$('#quantity').val();
 var amt=rate*qty;
 document.getElementById("amount").setAttribute('amt',amt);
});
```

To get attr :

```
var amt = document.getElementById("amount").getAttribute('amt');
```